# Unable to login to specific user under sddm on Arch

Tags: sddm

**PROBLEM:**

Unable to pass beyond login screen (sddm) using correct credentials.

**WHAT HAPPENS:**

After boot to cli, I `systemctl start sddm`, it gives me the usual login screen.  I **click my user, enter password, hit enter and the field freezes.**  I can still move the cursor, but can no longer interact with any user portraits/fields etc.

- If I leave it for several hours, nothing has changed.  I can only get
  away from this by `systemctl stop sddm`.
- If I try **entering the wrong password, it tells me such** and I can try again.
- If I try **logging in to a different user, this works**,

...leading me to believe it could be something about the user's config causing it.

**ATTEMPTS TO FIX/DIAGNOSE:**

I've appended `BAK` to all `.bash**` files under the affected user.  This has no affect to the outcome.

Trying to start KDE manually with `startkde` results in `DISPLAY is not set or cannot connect to the X server`.

`~/.local/share/sddm/xorg-session.log` contains `/usr/bin/xauth: timeout in locking authority file ~/.Xauthority`

`No protocol specified`

There is no .Xauthority file present.

Comment: sounds like you're on the right track; the user's shell initialization files would be a good place to start; move them aside, then start adding back in pieces.

Comment: I renamed the .bash*** files, rebooted, tried to login, nothing changes, still hangs. Was there any other files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started focusing on the xauth error, did some research and found recommendations to use `strace xauth`, this gave me errors such as "permission denied", I checked and the user's home directory (top level and several child files/folders) had become owned by root.

So I did `chown -Rf <myuser>:<myusergroup>` the top level directory and now everything works fine whilst trying to login to the specific user within sddm/kde.